# Angular Simple Harmonic Motion - Axis passing through center of mass

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

The formula for angular SHM's Time period is $T=2π √(I/mgd)$

Here $Icm$ is the moment of inertia through the axis of rotation, and $d$ is the distance of center of mass from the axis of rotation.

What if the center of mass and Axis of rotation are the *same*? $d=0?$

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you have given is for the period of a [compound pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum#Compound_pendulum) with small oscillations.

As the axis of rotation (which is horizontal) gets closer to the centre of mass the restoring couple about the axis exerted by the weight of the pendulum decreases, and the period of the pendulum increases. If the axis of rotation passes through the centre of mass then the weight of the pendulum exerts no restoring couple about the axis and oscillations are no longer possible - in effect the period has become infinite.

Comment: Thank you, this clear it up really well!